# Cauchy's Postulate

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

[image]

According to the Cauchy Postulate, the stress vector (***T***)^(***n***) remains unchanged for all surfaces passing through the point ***P*** and having the same normal vector ***n*** at ***P*** i.e., having a common tangent at ***P***. This means that the stress vector is a function of the normal vector ***n***  only, and is not influenced by the curvature of the internal surfaces.

**source**: Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Cauchy%E2%80%99s_postulate

So, traction vector or stress only exist at internal surfaces? What about the external surface of the continuum body (boundary surface)?

Comment: Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Thank you Emilio for the reference

Comment: This follows from the principle of local action for the stress tensor.  It only depends on the deformations at the immediate point under consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the surface is internal or external, all what matters is that a traction vector is a unit surface vector that acts on the surface of a body ( particles at the surface) and not on the interior of the body. Otherwise it would  a body force vector that acts on the interior of a body (example: gravity force vector).